# Xcode 6 doesn't recognize \1, \2, \# patterns anymore?

Tags: regex, xcode

In Xcode 5 I could do search-and-replaces like this:

```
(regex)
   find: \[([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+)\]
replace: \0.\1
```

In order to switch from syntax like `[ble bla]` to `ble.bla`. But when I do these sorts of searches in Xcode 6, I now turn `[ble bla]` into `0.1`.

How do I use groups from the find as part of the replace?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use `$#` instead of `\#` to refer to the groups.

```
(regex)
   find: \[([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+)\]
replace: $0.$1
```

Comment: Does anyone know  the rationale for this change?

Comment: @mts One possible guess: so that you can follow a group with a digit. $123\4 means the 123'rd group then the character 4 instead of the 123'rd group then the 4'th group.

Comment: $# is closer to Perl regex semantics, but who knows why Apple would have changed?

Comment: Update for Xcode 11: `$0` refers to the whole search expression, while `$1` refers to the first capture group.